# Using regex to transform data into a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, bioinformatics

I have a dataset with [FASTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format) formatted sequencing, basically like this:

```
>pc284  
ATCGCGACTCGAC

>pc293  
ACCCGACCTCAGC
```

I want to take to use each tag as a key in the dictionary, and store the gene as a value.

This is the code I have, but really isn't doing anything:

```
import re
fileData = open('d.fasta', 'r')

myDict = dict()

for line in fileData:
  match = re.search('(\>)(\w+)(\r)(\w+)', line)
  if match: 
    gene = match.group(3)
    myDict[gene[0]] = gene[1]

print myDict
```

Comment: You cannot match a carriage return `\r` since you already scan the file line by line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\r` is not a valid character class, I think you meant to use `\s` instead. You can reduce the groups if you don't use them either.

But most of all, you need to extract your groups correctly:

```
match = re.search(r'>(\w+)\s+(\w+)', line)
if match:
    tag, gene = match.groups()
    myDict[tag] = gene
```

By creating only *two* capturing groups, we can more simply extract those two with `.groups()` and directly assign them to two variables, `tag` and `gene`.

However, reading up on the [FASTA format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format) seems to indicate this is a multi-line format with the tag on one line, the gene data on *multiple* lines after that. In that case your `\r` was meant to match the newline. This won't work as you read the file one line at a time.

It would be much simpler to read that format without regular expressions like so:

```
myDict = {}

with open('d.fasta', 'rU') as fileData:
    tag = None
    for line in fileData:
        line = line.strip()
        if not line:
            continue
        if line[0] == '>':
            tag = line[1:]
            myDict[tag] = ''
        else:
            assert tag is not None, 'Invalid format, found gene without tag'
            myDict[tag] += line

print myDict
```

This reads the file line by line, detecting tags based on the starting `>` character, then reads *multiple* lines of gene information collecting it into your dictionary under the most-recently read tag.

Note the `rU` mode; we open the file using python's [universal newlines mode](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines), to handle whatever newline convention was used to create the file.

Last but not least; take a look at the [BioPy project](http://biopython.org/wiki/Main_Page); their [`Bio.SeqIO` module](http://biopython.org/wiki/SeqIO) handles FASTA plus many other formats perfectly.

Comment: @log0: it is supported as a regular character, which means it won't work when reading a file line by line.

Comment: When I try this, it is storing the entire genetic information as one tag, and not into separate values.

Comment: @gr8skillz: are there any newlines or `\r` characters in the genetic info stored as one value?

Comment: The code works for my simple test input, but if the file isn't properly split on line endings it'll fail.

Comment: @gr8skillz: I added a `U` to the file open() call. If that doesn't work for you, can you provide me with a sample file?

Comment: Yes @Martjin Pieters, I'm getting something like ['vpr75\rATGATGAAGTCTTTCACATCCTACTAGT\r>rc3\rATGATGAGCTTT': ''}

Comment: @gr8skillz: Right, then the file uses the (old) macintosh convention. Opening with `rU` should help.

Answer (score 1):

Two errors I see:

Your regex is probably wrong. It's unlikely your [FASTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format) input actually contains a bare carriage return (`\r`), so your regex won't match anything. Hence the `if match:` test is always false, so nothing happens.

Further, when processing each match: You are adding the first character of the `gene` (which is whitespace) as a key and the second character as the value.

You probably meant to use groups 2 and 4 respectively:

```
myDict[match.group(2)] = match.group(4)
```

Answer (score 1):

dont use a regex for this ...

```
class FASTA(object):
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data.strip().splitlines()
        self.desc = self.data[0]
        self.sequence = "".join(self.data[1:]).replace(" ","")#get rid of spaces
    def  GetCodons(self):
        return [self.sequence[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(self.sequence),3)]
    def __str__(self):
        return "DESC:'%s'\nSEQ:'%s'"%(self.desc,self.sequence)

with open("data.fasta") as f:
      data = f.read()
parts = data.split(">")
for p in parts[1:]:
    f= FASTA(p)
    print f
    print f.GetCodons()
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless your file is too big to fit in memory (which I guess it is not), the whole thing is as simple as

```
with open('d.fasta') as fp:
    myDict = dict(re.findall(r'(?m)^>(\w+)\s+^(\S+)', fp.read()))
```