# ValueError: too many values too unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python

I'm trying to parse DNA strings.

The input.txt contains:

> Rosalind_6404CCTGCGGAAGATCGGCACTAGAATAGCCAGAACCGTTTCTCTGAGGCTTCCGGCCTTCCCTCCCACTAATAATTCTGAGG>Rosalind_5959CCATCGGTAGCGCATCCTTAGTCCAATTAAGTCCCTATCCAGGCGCTCCGCCGAAGGTCTATATCCATTTGTCAGCAGACACGC>Rosalind_0808CCACCCTCGTGGTATGGCTAGGCATTCAGGAACCGGAGAACGCTTCAGACCAGCCCGGACTGGGAACCTGCGGGCAGTAGGTGGAAT

The code is:

```
f = open('input.txt', 'r')
raw_samples = f.readlines()
f.close()
samples = {}
cur_key = ''
for elem in raw_samples:
    if elem[0] == '>':
        cur_key = elem[1:].rstrip()
        samples[cur_key] = ''
    else:
        samples[cur_key] = samples[cur_key] + elem.rstrip()
print(samples)
for p_id, s in samples.values():
    samples[s_id] = (s.count('G') + s.count('C'))*100
print (samples)`
```

I keep getting the error:

> ```
>   File "C:/Python34/test.py", line 18, in <module>
>     for p_id, s in samples.values():
> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
> ```

Comment: What did you expect to get for `p_id` and `s` here? You are trying to unpack the values (strings) into two variables but you only have the one string with more than 2 characters in them. Did you mean to use `samples.items()` instead?

Comment: `for p_id, s in samples.values()`  iterates a one dimensional list as if it was a two dimensional list.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure using a dictionary to concatenate the continuation lines is the right approach for reading a FASTA file.

Comment: Last but not least, what is `s_id` supposed to mean?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters do you have another approach?

Comment: Are the lines not starting with `>` not just continuations of the DNA sequence? Let me look for older answers of mine.

Comment: I handled some [FASTA reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611491/using-regex-to-transform-data-into-a-dictionary-in-python/12611576#12611576) before using the same technique you are using, but the line format didn't include the DNA sequence on that first line like you have in your question here.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the problem by changing 
`for p_id, s in samples.values()` to 
`for p_id, s in samples.items()`

I also noticed that p_id and s_id were different, they were meant to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open("input.txt"), delimiter=">", quotechar="'")
dkeys = [item for item in next(reader) if item.strip()]
dvalues = [(item.count('G')+item.count('C')*100) for item in dkeys]
print(dict(zip(dkeys, dvalues)))
```

I hope it's useful. :D